# C# LINQ optimization

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

What would be the proper way of optimizing the following kind of statements:

```
IEnumerable<T> sequence = BuildSequence();
// 'BuildSequence' makes some tough actions and uses 'yield return'
// to form the resulting sequence.
```

Now, if I'm willing to take only some of the first elements, I could use something like:

```
sequence.Take(5);
```

And so, if my sequence from `BuildSequence` actually contains several thousands of elements, I obviously don't want all of them to be constructed, because I would only need 5 of them.

*Does `LINQ` optimize this kind of operations or I would have to invent something myself?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *iterator block* (`yield return`) handles this for you; an iterator block is a *streaming* API; work only happens during each `MoveNext()` call on the iterator (or on `Dispose()`). Because `Take()` *also* doesn't read the entire stream, this behaviour is preserved.

Note, however, that some operations need to buffer the data locally - `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` most notably; but as long as you use non-buffering operations, you are fine.

For example:

```
static IEnumerable<int> ReadInts() {
    var rand = new Random();
    while(true) yield return rand.Next();
}
...
int count = ReadInts().Take(10).Count(); // 10 - it doesn't loop forever
```

Comment: That while loop looks quite frightening at first site, and in all honesty I could see some developers freaking out if they saw that in source code and didn't have an understanding of how enumeration/yield works.

Comment: @m-y almost reason enough to add it to the code - to give them a reason to freak out and learn

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look on this:

[LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: strictly speaking, this relates more to buffered/non-buffered that it does to deferred. A deferred but buffered operation would still have to consume the entire set of data... simply "not quite now".